# How can I use perl for logic conditions of summing up two diffrent fileds

Tags: perl

How can I use perl to sum up individual fields in two rows in perl

e.g.

```
1st row (headers):-  A|B|C|D|E|F
2nd row (values) :-  Z|date|ABC10|100.32|200.32
3rd row (values) :- Y|Date|ABC10|100.22|150.22
4th tow          :-  Z|Date|ABC22|122.2|23
```

I want to add values of E and F for 2nd and 3rd row.  and condition is A for one row should be = Z and other row should be equal = Y
B and C fields in 2nd and 3rd row should be equal.

there are total 200 rows, and whenver the condition A = Z, And Y occurs I have to add these two rows.

Comment: Column `F` doesn't exist in the 2nd and 3rd rows though...

Comment: 1st row (headers):-  A|B|C|D|E|F
2nd row (values) :-  Z|date|ABC10|0|100.32|200.32
3rd row (values) :- Y|Date|ABC10|0|100.22|150.22
4th tow          :-  Z|Date|ABC22|0|122.2|23

here is updated input.

Comment: Have you tried writing any code? If so, add it to your question so that we can see what's going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Update: Your question is now slightly clearer, so I've updated the code. Now it will add columns D and E provided that they belong to conditions Y or Z. For your input this will sum rows 2 - 4:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my @sums;
while (<$input>){
    my @split = split(/\|/);
    next unless /^Y|Z/;
    my $add = ($split[3] + $split[4]);
    push @sums, $add;
}

print Dumper \@sums;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '300.64',
          '250.44',
          '145.2'
        ];
```

Comment: Thanks, it means first I need to check the condition,

I want to select two rows from 200 rows in which 
for 1 row , A = Z and for other row A = Y ,

and B and C values for these two records should also be equal,

and when this condition is satisfied, (I will get two rows for these condition)

then I want to add E and F columns for these row.
I guess, I have to write a 2-D array for conditions and Another additional array inside for summing.

Comment: e.g here for 2nd and 3rd row condition is satisfied.

Comment: @user3129274 - OK I think I know what you mean. It can of course be done, but I'm not going to do it for you unless you show some evidence of having tried first. Please do not re-post the same question under a different title - it will generally make people less willing to help you...

Comment: @user3129274 - why not?